# How to iterate a map datastructure in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on Google App Script, and  here I am storing some data in a map data-structure.
I am able to save the data, and print its content using Logger, but I am not finding a way to iterate its elements in a loop.

Can somebody please help me to iterate  the map elements in a loop in App Script.

Thanks in advance,
Saurabh

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide your current script and the detail of your current issue of your script and the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: for(const key of item_req.keys())
{
  Logger.log(key);
}

Here the map item_req isn't empty, but still  it is not printing elements of the map.
Can you please suggest how to make it work, in respect of Google App Script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can create an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) object:

```
const iterator1 = map1[Symbol.iterator]();

for (const item of iterator1) {
  console.log(item);
```

### Solution 2

You can also use the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) method to iterate on all the values:

```
for (const [k, v] of map1.entries()) {
  console.log(k, v)
}
```

### References:

- [Map.prototype[@@iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator)
- [Map.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)

### update

Both solutions work correctly in Apps Script, you can check it with the code below. I think the problem is in your map object. How do you create it? Can you give an example of what your data looks like?

```
function test() {
  const map1 = new Map();

  map1.set('Jessie', { phone: "123", address: "123 N 1st Ave" })
  map1.set('John', { phone: "456", address: "456 N 1st Ave" })
  map1.set('Maggie', { phone: "789", address: "789 N 1st Ave" })


  console.log('solution 1')
  const iterator1 = map1[Symbol.iterator]();

  for (const item of iterator1) {
    console.log(item)
  }

  console.log('solution 2')
  for (const [k, v] of map1.entries()) {
    console.log(k, v)
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello Fullfine, thanks for your response. But unfortunately both of these solutions doesn't seem to be working with Google App Script. I made sure that map isn't empty and I tried to print the map elements using Logger.log(item);, but it isn't printing anything.

Comment: I think there is something specific to Google App Script and its not a normal javascript. Can you please suggest a solution specific to Google App Script.

Comment: @saurabh Recently, I had the same problem. I used the forEach method: `myMap.forEach( ( value, key ) => { console.log( key, value ) } );`